# Definition of matrix valued smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, reference-request, operator-theory, matrix-calculus

Denote by $Sym_n$ the set of symmetric matrices on $\Bbb R^n$ and let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a real analytic function.

Then it is well known how to associate in a real analytic manner to an element $S \in Sym_n$ a matrix $f(S) \in Sym_n$. For example one can use Cauchy's formula in a suitable manner, as pointed out on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function#Cauchy_integral.

My question is: how to carry out the construction if $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is only smooth, i.e., how to define the matrix $f(S)$ in this case?

I suspect that this should be possible, if not otherwise, then by uniformly approximating $f$ on compact intervals by (real analytic) polynomials, but I am hoping for a direct treatment without approximation.

My hope is that polished references can be quoted on this by people in the know-how, and I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

A posteriori, $f(S)$ can be constucted as follows.

Diagonalise $S$, that is choose $M$ so that $M^{-1}SM$ is diag$(x_1,\dots,x_n)=A$. Then $f(S)=Mf(A)M^{-1}$ and $f(A)=$diag$(f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n))$.

So you could use this definition in the general case.

Comment: I understand, however I have a number of problems with this definition, it involves a choice of orthonormal base, that you need for each individual base. Because of this, it is hard to use this definition in my work. Can the definition be given canonically?

Comment: For example how can one prove using your definition that $S \to f(S)$ is even continous in operator norm?